# Android AsyncTask Context Terminated

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-context, terminate

When an Activity terminates, e.g. after screen orientation changing, is that possible to change an `AsyncTask` activity context? Else it will create an error because when the activity terminates `AsyncTask`'s activity context is gone too.

My homework done is the following:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) <- doesn't solve
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()  <- doesn't solve
```

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
                     <- solved but doesn't handle well relative layouts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you pass on your `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`? What I do is pass an object to it containing the `AsyncTask`, and then I try to retrieve the value in `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`.

EDIT: On second thought, it would depend on what you want to do after a configuration change. If you want to terminate the `AsyncTask`, and then call `cancel()` on it. If you want to continue its processing even after an orientation change, then you have to hold on to the task.

You can do that by saving the `Activity` in the `AsyncTask` like this:

```
private MyAsyncTask searchTask;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
 super.onCreate(savedInstance);

 if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance()!=null) {
  SavedObject savedObj = (SavedObject)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

  searchTask = savedObj.getAsyncTask();
  searchTask.attach(this);
 } else {
  searchTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
  searchTask.execute();
 }
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(){

 searchTask.detach();

 final SavedObject savedObj = new SavedObject();
 savedObj.setAsyncTask(searchTask);

    return savedObj;
}


private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 MyActivity parentActivity = null;

    MyAsyncTask (MyActivity activity) {
  attach(activity);   
 }

 void attach(MyActivity activity) {
  this.parentActivity=activity;
 }

 void detach() {
  parentActivity=null;
 }

 // Do your thread processing here
}


private class SavedObject {
 private MyAsyncTask asyncTask;

 public void setAsyncTask(MyAsyncTask asyncTask){
  this.asyncTask = asyncTask;
 }

 public MyAsyncTask getAsyncTask() {
  return asyncTask;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the OnCancel method of your asynch task put finish();

```
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        cancel(true);
        dialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
```