# Can AsyncTask started from Activity cause problems if Activity is exited?

Tags: android, exception, user-interface, android-activity, android-asynctask

If I have an `AsyncTask` started in an `Activity` by user interaction. The `AsyncTask`, when finished, will modify the UI and execute a `Toast`. Let's say that the user exits the `Activity` before the `AsyncTask` has finished. Can this cause problems as in `Exceptions`: I.e. could it happen that an UI element pointer goes null and that when the `AsyncTask` finishes it could cause runtime exceptions?

As it is now I've done a design where the `Application` class handles the `AsyncTask` and notifies the `Activity` through a `BroadcastReceiver` to do UI tasks if `Activity` still is around (i.e. more of an Observer pattern). Is this a "safer" design?

/ Henrik

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does cause a problem. If the activity that created the `AsyncTask` is not around anymore, the an exception is thrown because the parent handler is not there anymore. The correct approach is to keep the reference of the `AsyncTask` in that activity, and capture `onPause()` event. In the pause event, I **would cancel** the `AsyncTask` and clean up if there is anything that needs to be cleaned up.

To answer your second question, it all depends on what is the requirement. If the requirement is for that task to still be around then yes you can attach the `AsyncTask` to the application. But it sounds like there is something that might be not correct here. You said `if Activity still is around`. If you don't need the task once the activity has disappeared then you might as well go with my original approach which is cancel the task and throw it away when the activity is paused.

Also, one final note. If you keep a reference to the activity around even after the activity has stopped, you will have a *memory leak* because that activity still has a reference that cannot be cleaned up until the task has completed.

This [article](http://www.fattybeagle.com/2011/02/15/android-asynctasks-during-a-screen-rotation-part-ii/) sounds similar to what you are doing. If you really want to keep the task around then this seems like a good solution. I also found [Android AsyncTask Context Terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404993/android-asynctask-context-terminated) that might help you.